# got error when i run the npm install command

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular5

```
Got error 

npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
```

npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed using git.
    npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sweta.sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-24T06_47_16_940Z-debug.log
```

Comment: can you add more info ? code, description

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you don't have GIT installed or it has not been added to your path.

First solution is to install git.

If it is already installed try adding it to your path and then restarting your terminal:

It looks like you are on windows so:

- Type environment variables into the windows search box
- Select 'Edit the system environment variables'
- Click Environment Variables in the bottom of the window
- Then under System Variables look for the path variable and click edit
- Add the directory path to git’s bin:

```
;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

(PLEASE NOTE: Your installation path may be different so confirm where it is installed at first)